# Problem with using Read10x function of Seurat

Tags: r, seurat, loaddata

I am trying to follow the tutorial from Seurat website and try to import a dataset I find on Github to better practice the tutorial.
https://satijalab.org/seurat/v3.1/pbmc3k_tutorial.html
I encountered this problem. I know the ending of my file is not the right format ( it should be a tsv file instead), but the only file I can download is in csv. What should I do to approach this problem?

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbQCu.png)

This is the link to the data I'm trying to download: https://figshare.com/articles/dataset/SEATRAC_TB_Hackday_2023/24425053?file=42875377 and I'm trying to download darrah's data set.

I tried to convert csv to tsv but I coul't find a way.

Comment: Take a look at the convert function from the rio package to convert csv to tsv https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rio/vignettes/rio.html

Answer (score 0):

`Seurat::Read10X` expects a directory of files in the 10X format. The data you linked to looks like a .tsv file, so you should read it into R using a function meant for tabular data. The file is large, so `read.table()` is too slow. You can use `data.table::fread()`instead.

```
library(Seurat)
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("darrah_Week25.Filtered.cells.txt")
mat <- as.matrix(dat[,-1])
rownames(mat) <- dat$V1
mat <- as.sparse(mat)
seurat <- CreateSeuratObject(mat)
```

Edit:
The file is large, so if memory is an issue, a range of columns can be specified. That way it may be possible to read in all the data in chunks.

```
genes <- fread("darrah_Week25.Filtered.cells.txt", select = 1)
dat <- fread("darrah_Week25.Filtered.cells.txt", select = 2:5000)
mat1 <- as.sparse(as.matrix(dat))
dat <- fread("darrah_Week25.Filtered.cells.txt", select = 5001:10000)
mat2 <- as.sparse(as.matrix(dat))
```

Choose suitable column ranges and repeat as needed. It may help to run garbage collection manually with `gc()` to free up memory. Finally, cbind the subsets:

```
mat <- cbind(mat1, mat2)
rownames(mat) <- genes$V1
```

Comment: Hi, I follow your instruction code but I got this below. I think it's because of the file is too large. Do you have any idea what I should do? Thanks a lot for your help                                > mat <- as.sparse(mat)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 24.1 Gb
> seurat <- CreateSeuratObject(mat)
Warning: Data is of class matrix. Coercing to dgCMatrix.
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 24.1 Gb

Comment: @OliviaViVi It is a large file, so you need quite a lot of memory to work with it. If you just want to test the analysis, you can read in a subset by specifying a range of columns: `fread("darrah_Week25.Filtered.cells.txt", select = 1:5000)`.

Comment: @OliviaViVi You can try reading in the data in chunks, see the edit above. Sparse matrices take less space than tables or regular matrices, so it could work.